# detecting if running with pytest

Tags: pytest

I have a test function that generates some results I can automatically check, but ideally if running manually, I wanted the test function to plot some charts. Example:

```
def test_my_func():
    output = my_func() 
    if not running_in_pytest():
        plot_my_output(output)
```

The ideia is that `plot_my_output(output)` should not run when I'm executing a batch of tests with pytest, only if a happen to run this function some other way (such as manually)

Comment: How a test would not be running with pytest?

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the following env variable is set as explained here --  https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#pytest-current-test-environment-variable

```
import psutil

for pid in psutil.pids():
    environ = psutil.Process(pid).environ()
    if "PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST" in environ:
        print(f'pytest process {pid} running: {environ["PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST"]}')
```

Comment: Note: this answer checks to see whether _pytest_ is running *anywhere* on the computer... If you want to know whether the running your code is pytest, you could simply test `os.environ` instead of looping through all pids.